# Connect to python server in different network

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

[My port forward rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9w9I.png)
I've created a python TCP server and client which is working fine when I launch both server and client on my computer and when I launch the server and the client on different computers on the same network, however I wanted to make it work when computers are in different networks. I have forwarded my router port 8080 to convert to 8888 in my computer, in fact I have also a rule for the port 80 on my router converting to 8080 on my PC which is the Wamp server, and as the python server is not working I guessed it was from the code but I can't figure it out:

Server:

```
import socket

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sck.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8888))               

sck.listen(1)    
conn, adr = sck.accept()
print('Connected to ', adr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    if data and ('over' not in data):
        conn.send(data.encode())
        continue
    break
conn.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sck.connect(('<my_external_ip>', 8888))

while True:
    data = input('Say something: ')
    if 'Shut up' in data:
        sck.send('over'.encode())
        sck.close
        break
    sck.send(data.encode())
```

I've made this test:

  Started Wamp server and tried to access it by my external ip with chrome (working)

  Opened my Python TCP Client and connected to the Wamp server (working)

  Turned Wamp off and started my python server with the same port as Wamp, then tried to acess with the python client (not working)

If there's nothing wrong with the TCP Server code why does Wamp work and he don't? Please check the following - Whats the logic behind binding 127.0.0.1 I couldn't understand... Won't that make it only be accessible by my PC?

If that part is ok than at least is something related to the Server code I guess...

Comment: `sck.bind(("192.168.1.120", 8888))` might be the problem you're having. Have you tried `sck.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8888))`?

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Does it work on your original computer if both, the server and client connect to 127.0.0.1? If so, try it on the other network as well

Comment: Couldn't understand: It works on my PC with 127.0.0.1 on client and server so am is supposed to try it with 127.0.0.1 on the server and mantain the external ip on the client on a different network?

Comment: If you're launching the server on a different network, the IP needs to be localhost (or 127.0.0.1). The client then has to connect that THAT computer's port forwarded external address.
If it's working on your network but not the other, the issue is the IP addresses the client/server is connecting to.

Comment: Doesn't work yet... What can I do if the problem is the IP adresses?

Comment: Perhaps the other network is not port forwarded correctly. Are you sure the port is forwarded and that the firewall isn't blocking the incoming/outgoing port?

Comment: Just to verify: I have to create a rule in firewall for external or internal port?(Added photography of the router page on top)

Comment: Your port forwarding rule must also have an IP address to forward to, i.e. your server’s IP address 192.168.1.120. Click the ‘Assign a game or application a local network device’ and set it up there. If that still doesn’t work, try NOT changing port range, i.e. use 8080 or 8888 for both port numbers

Comment: The server and the client still can't reach each other... I've updated the question. Any suggestions left?